# jQuery wrap multiple ids with div

Tags: jquery, html, wrapper

I was trying to wrap selected sets of ids with a div and wrap other sets with different one, but not quite sure how it should work.

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="block_1">
        <div class="post">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="block_2">
        <div class="post">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="block_3">
        <div class="post">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="block_4">
        <div class="post">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="block_5">
        <div class="post">
        </div>
</div>
```

And want to use Jquery to make two different of sets wrapped with another div, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="wrapright">
    <div id="block_1">
            <div class="post">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block_4">
            <div class="post">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block_5">
            <div class="post">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapleft">
    <div id="block_2">
            <div class="post"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="block_3">
            <div class="post"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you see, I want to wrap `block 1,4,5` with `class="wrapright"` and wrap block 2,3 with `class="wrapleft"`

is there a Jquery way that I can do this!! I found some ways, but all for single set, not multiple...

your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use .wrapAll().

If the ids and element set are constant then you can just

```
$('#block_1, #block_4, #block_5').wrapAll('<div class="wrapright" />');
$('#block_2, #block_3').wrapAll('<div class="wrapleft" />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zcvkw51u/)

---

If the element sets are not constant then you need to come up with a logic on how to determine the groups.

Comment: perfect... That did the job! Thanks @[Arun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)