# jQuery wrapAll not working with WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29360164/15172428), I came up with the following JS to add to a WordPress site:

```
jQuery('#working-with-us-top, #working-with-us-bottom').wrapAll('<div id="working-with-us" />');
```

This is in a JS file, which is being loaded okay with jQuery as a dependency, and `#working-with-us-top` `#working-with-us-bottom` exist in the document, however, they're not being wrapped in `<div id="working-with-us">`

The [codepen](https://codepen.io/SteveMH/pen/MWbbXeQ) of this code works properly.

Could WordPress be complicating things somehow?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Try to use above code in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: Thanks, @MominIqbal, that worked, add an answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use above code in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { });`

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)